# Open Graph Protocol, Facebook App & Facebook Like Button on Website

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

So I set up an App to handle open graph protocol setting for my website.  I embedded the open graph protocol metadata into the site and I added a Facebook like button that ties to the home page.  I ran it through the linter and everything looks good.  But when I look at the administration interface in Facebook, it shows a different number of "likes" than on my page itself.  Also I thought by setting it up in this way I would be able to see who liked my page as well.  Finally, when I go to my website and I am logged into facebook, it does not show an "admin page" link which I thought it is supposed to do.  I have been looking all over the Facebook developer documentation and cannot seem to find an answer.  Thank you!